# Neo4j cypher query to see whether given nodes are connected

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given the following nodes B,E,F,G,H,J,K. I have to write a neo4j query to check how these nodes are connected each other.

For example, suppose this is the pattern I want to display.

```
B-H-F 
  |
  G-J-K-E
```

What is the query to display this graph? I don't want to display all other nodes which are connected to these nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the paths between each pair of source nodes.

Make sure that each path consists of only those nodes that are included in the source set.

You can do this with a cypher:

```
WITH {GIVEN_NODES} as NDS // The source array of node IDs
UNWIND RANGE(0, size(NDS)-2) as i
UNWIND RANGE(i+1, size(NDS)-1) as j
WITH NDS,
     NDS[i] as N1,
     NDS[j] as N2
MATCH path = (N1)-[*]-(N2) 
      WHERE length(path)+1 <= size(NDS) AND
      ALL(n in nodes(path) WHERE n in NDS)
RETURN path
```